# How to pass extras to a dynamic shortcut?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am writing a simple coupon application and I want to implement launcher shortcuts so I'd be able to quickly generate coupons without going into my application.

The problem is that I generate coupons with images. These images are generated from intent extras. I pass the image as an "extra" to my coupon generator.

When I create a static shortcut, I can pass an intent extra and my coupon can be generated, but I don't know what to do with a dynamic shortcut.

I want a dynamic shortcut because I load my images with "R.drawable.coupon_cheeseburger", that's why I can't use it with static shortcuts.

[image: kotlin]

```
package com.szakes1.makdolannative.activities

import android.content.pm.ShortcutInfo
import android.content.pm.ShortcutManager
import android.graphics.drawable.Icon
import android.os.Build
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.content.getSystemService
import androidx.viewpager.widget.PagerAdapter
import androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
import com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
import com.szakes1.makdolannative.R
import com.szakes1.makdolannative.adapters.ViewPagerAdapter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var tabLayout: TabLayout
    private lateinit var viewPager: ViewPager
    private lateinit var pagerAdapter: PagerAdapter

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 25) {
            val shortcutManager = getSystemService<ShortcutManager>(ShortcutManager::class.java)

            val shortcut = ShortcutInfo.Builder(context, "hamburger")
                .setShortLabel("Hamburger")
                .setLongLabel("Wygeneruj kod dla hamburgera")
                .setIcon(Icon.createWithResource(context, R.drawable.ic_burger))
                .setExtras()
        }



        // Sets color for Navigation and Status Bar
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
            val color = ContextCompat.getColor(applicationContext, R.color.colorPrimaryDark)

            window.statusBarColor = color
            window.navigationBarColor = color
        }

        tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabLayout)
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.viewPager)
        pagerAdapter = ViewPagerAdapter(supportFragmentManager, 5)

        viewPager.adapter = pagerAdapter
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager, true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried putting the extras on the `Intent` that you attach to the shortcut via [`setIntent()` on your `ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/pm/ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder.html#setIntent(android.content.Intent))?